# Why isn't my UIAlertController appearing when it is called?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I currently have a button on one of my View Controllers which once selected, should display a UIAlertController which allows the user to enter in some text. I have created a segue between the button and the Swift file, however once the button is selected, my Alert Controller isn't appearing. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

 class OnlineAccountsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func editEbayName(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Edit your Ebay name", message: "Please enter your new Ebay name", preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.addTextField()
    
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default))
        
    let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default) { _ in
        if let answer = ac.textFields?.first?.text {
            
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            
            let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

            db.collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    } else {
                        for document in snapshot!.documents {
                            let data = document.data()
                            let userId = data["uid"] as! String
                            if userId == user?.uid {
                                
                                document.reference.updateData([
                                  "ebayname":(answer)
                                ])
                                
         }
        }
       }         
      }         
     }
    }
   }
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to get it working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Where about would that need to be added? Feel free to edit my original question to indicate the position. :)

Comment: add at last line in method.
i was edit your post, but need moderation

Comment: Perfect thank you!